# PHP session class doesn't work

Tags: php, class, function, session, pdo

I have build this session class using this [article](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL).. I am really sure that I have followed all the rules and all the information given, but my code doesn't work.

**Session class: session.php**

```
 class Session {

     function __construct() {

         // set our custom session functions
         session_set_save_handler(
             array($this, 'open'),
             array($this, 'close'),
             array($this, 'read'),
             array($this, 'write'),
             array($this, 'destroy'),
             array($this, 'gc')
         );

         // This line prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handlers
         register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

     }

     function start_session($session_name, $secure) {

         // Make sure the session cookie is not accessable via javascript
         $httponly = true;

         // Hash algorith to use for the session_id
         $session_hash = 'sha512';

         // Check if hash is available
         if (in_array($session_hash, hash_algos())) {

             // Set the hash function
             ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);

         }

         // How many bits per character of the hash
         ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);

         // Force the session to only use cookies, nut URL variables
         ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

         // Get session cookie parameters
         $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

         // Set the parameters
         session_set_cookie_params(
            $cookieParams['lifetime'],
            $cookieParams['path'],
            $cookieParams['domain'],
            $secure,
            $httponly
         );

         // Change the sesion name
         session_name($session_name);

         // Now we can start the session
         session_start();

         // This line regenerates the session and delete the old one
         // It also generates a new encryption key in the database 
         session_regenerate_id(true);    

     }

     function open() {

         // Define Connection variables
         $host = '';
         $user = '';
         $pass = '';
         $dbnm = '';

         // Connection string based on connection variables
         $PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbnm", $user, $pass);

         // Connect to DB based on connection string
         $this->db = $PDO;
         return true;

     }

     function close() {

         // Close DB connection
         $this->db->close();
         return true;

     }

     function read($id) {

         // If not the read statement is defined
         if(!isset($this->read_stmt)) {

             // Prepared statement for getting data from DB
             $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

         }

         $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);    // Replace ? with $id
         $this->read_stmt->execute();               // Execute the prepared statement
         $this->read_stmt->store_result();          // We store the data returned
         $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);      // We bind the result to a $data variable
         $this->read_stmt->fetch();                 // And fetch returned data

         // This function is defined later
         // but returns the session key based on the $id
         $key = $this->getkey($id);

         // Both the variabels are decrypted and assigned to $data
         $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);

         // We return the results
         return $data;

     }

     function write($id, $data) {

         // Get unique session key
         $key = $this->getkey($id);

         //Encrypt the data
         $data = $this->encrypt($data);

         // Assign current time to $time variable
         $time = time();

         // If not the write statement is defined
         if(!isset($this->write_stmt)) {

             // Prepared statement for replacing data in DB
             $this->write_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

         }

         $this->write_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);    // Replace ?, ?, ?, ? with $id, $time, $data, $key
         $this->write_stmt->execute();                                      // Execute the prepared statement

         // Return confirmation
         return true;

     }

     function destroy($id) {

         // If not the delete statement is defined
         if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {

             // Prepared statement for deleting session data from DB
             $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");

         }

         $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);  // Replace ? with $id
         $this->delete_stmt->execute();             // Execute the prepared statement

         // Return confirmation
         return true;

     }

     function gc($max) {

         // This function 'Garbage Collector' is emptying the DB for old sessions
         // this way, the DB takes care of itself.

         // If not the GC statement is defined
         if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {

             // Prepared statement for deleting session data from DB
             $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE set_time < ?");

         }

         // Define $old to be an old statement
         $old = time() - $max;

         $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old); // Replace ? with $old
         $this->gc_stmt->execute();             // Execute the prepared statement

         // Return confirmation
         return true;

     }

     private function getkey($id) {

         // This function is used to get the unique key for encryption from the sessions table.
         // If there is no session it just returns a new random key for encryption.

         // If not the select statement is defined
         if(!isset($this->key_stmt)) {

             // Prepared statement for selecting session key from DB
             $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM sessions WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

         }

         $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id); // Replace ? with $old
         $this->key_stmt->execute();            // Execute the prepared statement
         $this->key_stmt->store_result();       // We store the data returned

         // If the select statement returns a row
         if($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) {

             $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);    // We bind the result to a $data variable
             $this->read_stmt->fetch();             // And fetch returned data

             // Then we return the result
             return $key;

         } else {

             // We generate a random key
             $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

             // Then we return the result
             return $random_key;

         }

     }

     private function encrypt($data, $key) {

         // A complete random key for encryption
         $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';

         // We assign a hash encoded version of the random key and session key to the $key
         $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);

         // Open module, and create IV
         $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
         $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

         // Do the encryption and assign it to $encrypted
         $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));

         // And return the encrypted data
         return $encrypted;

     }

     private function decrypt($data, $key) {

         // The same key for encryption is used for decrytion (obviously)
         $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';

         // We assign a hash encoded version of the random key and session key to the $key
         $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);

         // Open module, and create IV
         $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
         $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

         // Do the decryption and assign it to $decrypted
         $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

         // And return the decrypted data
         return $decrypted;

     }

 }
```

And then I have two pages for testing. I also believe those pages are written correctly, so there has to be something stopping the class from working.. I have a bigger script where I use the same class, and I am able to define the new class `$session = new Session();` but when I start the session `$session->start_session('test', false);` the script dies.

**Test page PHP: tester.php**

```
<?
require_once('session.php');
$session = new Session();

$session->start_session('test', false);

$_SESSION['dims'] = 'This is a session variable';

?>

<a href="tester2.php">click here</a>
```

**Test page 2 PHP: tester2.php**

```
<?
require_once('session.php');
$session = new Session();

$session->start_session('test', false);

echo $_SESSION['dims'];

?>
```

I found out that an error 500 internal server error appeared.

Comment: I tried that, but actually no errors appeared..

Comment: Well 500 error means server error, if your server is not unusual and you turn on logging (in your code and in server config) than you would see it. With clear error description we can help much faster.

Comment: wait.. I got this after adding `error_reporting (E_ALL);
 ini_set ('display_errors',true);` and starting the session in the script.. `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in (session_url) on line 117 Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::close() in (session_url) on line 102`

Comment: `bind_param()` is a MySQLi method.  For PDO, you need `bindParam()`.

Comment: All your methods on that prepared statement are MySQLi methods, but apparently you have connected using the PDO API. The two are not compatible.

Comment: -.-' seriously? damnit!

Comment: Could I humbly ask for some help 'translating' the MySQLi to PDO?

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted That should get you started...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has established its connection via PDO, but the tutorial you are following uses MySQLi prepared statements. The two APIs are not compatible with one another.  The equivalent code in PDO would look like:

```
     // If not the read statement is defined
     if(!isset($this->read_stmt)) {

         // Prepared statement for getting data from DB
         // Prepare using the named parameter :id instead of ? (though ? can be used in PDO too)
         $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");

     }
     // If the statement was successfully prepared...
     if ($this->read_stmt) {
         // One of 2 param binding methods in PDO...
         $this->read_stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
         $this->read_stmt->execute(); 
         // No correlate for store_result() in PDO...

         // Fetch the first row and get the data key from it
         // You don't need to do a bind result in PDO. Instead just fetch() or fetchAll()
         // more like the old mysql_fetch_*() functions.
         $row = $this->read_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $data = $row['data']

         // Do the rest of your stuff with data.
     }
```

I'm not going to translate your entire code block above, but this should get you started.  The [PDO docs on `bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) have enough examples that you should be able to figure out your other queries as well.

Finally, I recommend the [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), which has excellent examples, although it doesn't directly address translating MySQLi prepared statements to PDO statements.